# ActiveRecord rendering row_to_json as escaped string, how to render as pure JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to pull JSON from my PostGres database via row_to_json, but when I render it using something like this:

`render :status => 200, :json => sports`

```
[{"row_to_json"=>"{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Basketball\"}"}
{"row_to_json"=>"{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Football\"}"}
{"row_to_json"=>"{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"Baseball\"}"}]
```

It treats row_to_json's value as an escaped string, vs. the json.

Is there an easy way to convert this into a proper JSON object that is better than the brute force way of doing something like this:

```
new_sports_array = Array.new()
sports.each do |sport|
  new_sports_array.push(JSON.parse(sport[:]))
end
```

I'm assuming the above may put an unnecessary tax on my api.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey Please try this,

```
new_sports_array = []
sports.select{|s| new_sports_array << JSON.parse(s['row_to_json'])}
```

Comment: Yep, looks like this does the same thing, just more the Ruby way

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the standard Rails action?

```
def show_sports
  sports = Sports.where(conditions)
  render json: sports
end
```

Comment: I store JSON in a JSON field type in postgres, and when it returns data from the database into my Rails hash it always asigns the [field_name => {json_field}, field_name => {json_field}, ...] which is annoying as i just want [{json_field}, {json_field}, etc.]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a json string, you should be able to do something like this:

```
render text: <your json string>, content_type: 'application/json'
```

This will help you avoid the built-in to_json call that Rails makes.